# Can android wear access a content provider from the mobile device?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, wear-os

Since android wear and mobile are two separate devices, is the wear device able to access a public content provider from a custom app that's on the mobile once it is connected? Thanks.

edit: if you downvote, pls comment why, as your downvotes don't help me understand anything.

edit2: Ok, let me explain a little more. I'm creating a watch face that displays some useful data along with the time and to do that I need to access a content provider from my watch face. Can I access a content provider from an app thats on my phone through my android wear? So far my testing has been unsuccessful in trying to access a content provider directly through `getContentResolver()`.

I could use dataApi to send info to the wear device, but that would require the app also be running on the phone right? So question still remains, How would I retrieve content provider information from an app?

Comment: why can't you use the data api for this?

Comment: Yes you can, but that is not my question..

Comment: i know but if you explain why you need that and the alternatives you tried then you will get better responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the watch, you do not have direct access to the providers from the companion phone. The wearable support library provides access to the [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/provider/package-summary.html) and that is the only one that I can remember is available on the watch directly; for the rest, you need to go through the data layer APIs and have a phone component to retrieve the data and send it to or sync it across the watches.